# How can I make images stack on top of each other as web page scales down?

Tags: html, css

Basically there are two images that are supposed to be on the center of the page and when the page is made smaller those images need to stack vertically.  Currently I can get them to scale vertically, but I don't know how to center them.  If I use margins or padding they stay in their position when the page is shrunk and don't look very good.  I need them to move towards the edge as the page is being shrunk and then stack once the width of the page is too small.  I'm doing this so they display properly on mobile and smaller resolutions.  Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Here is the html:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="wordmark">
<a href="#">
<img src="........." />
</a>
</div>
</div>


<div class="logowrap">
<div class="row">
<ul class="thumbnails">


<div class="logo1">
<li class="span6 home-left">
<a href="#">
<img src="SDI-logo.png" alt="SDI-logo"  />
</a>
</li>
</div>

<div class="logo2">
<li class="span6 home-right">
<a href="#">
<img src="Debate-Logo.png" alt="SDI-logo"  />
</a>
</li>
</div>

</ul>


</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.navbar {
    background-color:#000;
}

.container{


    background-color:transparent;


}

.wrapper {
    background-color:#000;
}

.wordmark{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    padding-left:15px;
}

.logo1{
    float:left;




.logo2 {
    float:inherit;


}

.logowrap{


}
```

Comment: Have you looked into media queries?

Comment: Yes I considered those.  So will it also work if someone keeps their screen resolution the same, but changes the size of the browser.  For example when someone snaps the browser to the edge with win 7, the pictures should stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed your code a bit. Take a look [here](http://jsbin.com/UdODawI/1/) and see if that helps you (http://jsbin.com/UdODawI/1/)

```
   .thumbnails {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .wrapper {
        background-color:#000;
    }

    .logowrap {
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .logo1{
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .logo2 {
      display: inline-block;

    }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thanks a bunch.  So what exactly is allowing the pictures to be in the center?  Is it because of the text-align:center property for the logowrap class?

Comment: Yes, exactly! The text-align CSS property describes how inline content like text is aligned in its parent block element. text-align does not control the alignment of block elements itself, only their inline content. The standard-compatible way to center a block itself without centering its inline content is setting a width for the block and the left and right margin to auto.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this css to your image

```
.thumbnails img {
   max-width:100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

this allows your images to resize according to its parent

Comment: I don't want the images to resize.  Just stack on top of each other when the browser is shrunk.